# User associated with a socket

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, socket

I use `ss -p` to see TCP sockets information. But process info are not printed for some sockets. Below:

```
$ ss -p4
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port
ESTAB  0       0       10.146.18.213:50368  199.7.59.72:http
```

But with sudo, I can see the process info:

```
$ sudo ss -p4
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port
ESTAB  0       0       10.146.18.213:50368  199.7.59.72:http      users:(("sshd",473,18))
```

With `netstat -net`, no root, I can see the user:

```
$ netstat -net
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode
tcp        0      0 10.146.18.213:50368         199.7.59.72:80              ESTABLISHED 222        3693189
```

My user id is 222:

```
$ id -u
222
```

But ss shows process info only with root.

My questions are:

1. Why are there sockets with no user associated?
2. Are these sockets with no user subjected to the `owner` module matching of iptables?

Comment: Add the output of 'ss -p' to your question. Have you tried 'netstat -net' as root?

Comment: I have added them. Does `ss` do it right way?

Comment: Why do you think `iptables` is relevant here?

Comment: I am trying match the SSH tunnel traffic using iptables `owner` module. Have not get it work and wondering about the reason.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'd say your "sudo ss" shows connection related to user sshd, meanwhile "netstat -net" — to your own user. That's why netstat's version doesn't require sudo to find out the details regarding the socket.</strike>

You can use `ss -e` to get UID as well.

Comment: `sshd` is the process command name, not the user name. And 473 is the process id.

Comment: You said "But with sudo, I can see the user", that's why I thought it was username.

Comment: @fossilet, + actually, you can use `ss -e` to get UID as well.

Comment: @fossilet in other words, you were misled too since `ss` w/o `-e` shows not user name, but process name, which is hidden unless you're root or it's your own socket.

Comment: @fossilet, also my investigation shows that root is the only user whose uid `ss` avoids to mention :) even in despite of it's being invoked by root itself.